# Custom SSRS Data Processing Extension not listed on Server

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I wrote a custom data processing extension for SQL Server Reporting Services.
The Extension works fine in VS but I can't get it on my local Reporting Server.

I copied the extension dll to the bin directory of my server, then I added it to the rsreportserver.config like this:

```xml
<Extension Name="WEBAPI" Type="ExtensionAssembly.WebApiConnection, ExtensionAssembly"/>
```

and I added the CodeGroup to the rssrvpolicy.config file:

```xml
<CodeGroup
    class="UnionCodeGroup"
    version="1"
    PermissionSetName="FullTrust"
    Name="WebApi"
    Description="Code group for my Custom DataSource for data processing extension">
    <IMembershipCondition
        class="UrlMembershipCondition"
        version="1"
        Url="Path_To_Dll.dll"
        />
</CodeGroup>
```

Anybody Ideas what's wrong?

Comment: have you restarted your reporting service services?

Comment: yes, I did. I also tried restarting the whole system